# QGis QSpatialite plugin corrupting dates when importing layers

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

I'm using Qspatialite version 7.0.4 in QGis 2.14. We use QSpatialite to save selected polygons from an MSSQL (2008) layer into spatialite databases.

Since Qgis 2.14 we have noticed that any dates held in the SQL table as a date data type are corrupted when the data is imported into a spatialite database through QSpatialite.

Original Data from MSSQL layer within QGis:
[image: Original Data from MSSQL layer within QGis]

Data after importing into spatialite database using QSpatialite:
[image: After QSpatialite]

N.B the field name is the data type used to create the table in MSSQL.

I have tried using the DB manager and this fails stating 'Error 5 - creation of fields failed'

We currently have a workaround that involves using QGis 2.8 to import the layer and then opening it through QGis 2.14 to continue editing, this doesn't corrupt the data.

Does anyone have any experience of this? or any ideas of other things to try?

Please ask if you need any more information!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this issue: https://github.com/romain974/qspatialite/issues/24 but that should be closed. You might want to reopen it if it has resurfaced in the latest version.

Comment: Thank you! I have left a comment on that issue in github.